# OpenCL compute histogram program doesn't returns 0 in every bin

Tags: c++11, opencl

I'm trying to implement a simple opencl program to compute an histogram.
Below is what I currently have:

```
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>
#include <algorithm>

//Getting platform, device, context and command queue
void setup(
        cl_platform_id &platformId, cl_device_id &deviceId, cl_context& context, cl_command_queue& commandQueue,
        std::string platformName = "NVIDIA CUDA",  cl_device_type deviceType = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,
        std::string deviceName = "GeForce GTX 1070")
{

    using std::vector;
    using std::string;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    cl_uint numberOfPlatforms, numberOfDevices;
    cl_int error;

    //Finding platform id
    error = clGetPlatformIDs(0,nullptr,&numberOfPlatforms);
    vector<cl_platform_id> platform(numberOfPlatforms);
    error = clGetPlatformIDs(numberOfPlatforms,platform.data(),nullptr);

    for(const auto & currentPlatform : platform)
    {
        size_t stringSize;
        error = clGetPlatformInfo(currentPlatform,CL_PLATFORM_NAME,0,nullptr,&stringSize);
        char * currentPlatformName = new char[stringSize];
        error = clGetPlatformInfo(currentPlatform,CL_PLATFORM_NAME,stringSize,currentPlatformName,nullptr);
        if(string(currentPlatformName).compare(platformName) == 0)
        {
            cout << "Platform " << platformName << " found!" << endl;
            delete [] currentPlatformName;
            platformId = currentPlatform;
            break;
        }
        delete [] currentPlatformName;
    }

    error = clGetDeviceIDs(platformId,deviceType,0,nullptr,&numberOfDevices);
    vector<cl_device_id> device(numberOfDevices);
    error = clGetDeviceIDs(platformId,deviceType,numberOfDevices,device.data(),nullptr);

    for(const auto & currentDevice : device)
    {
        size_t stringSize;
        error = clGetDeviceInfo(currentDevice,CL_DEVICE_NAME,0,nullptr,&stringSize);
        char * currentDeviceName = new char[stringSize];
        error = clGetDeviceInfo(currentDevice,CL_DEVICE_NAME,stringSize,currentDeviceName,nullptr);

        if(string(currentDeviceName).compare(deviceName) == 0)
        {
            cout << "Device " << deviceName << " found!" << endl;
            delete [] currentDeviceName;
            deviceId = currentDevice;
            break;
        }
        delete [] currentDeviceName;
    }

    context = clCreateContext(nullptr,1,&deviceId,nullptr,nullptr,&error);
    commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context,deviceId,0,&error);

}

void run(const std::string & imagePath, const std::string& programSource, const cl_device_id deviceId,
        const cl_context& context, const cl_command_queue& commandQueue, int histogram[256])
{
    cl_int error;
    int width, height, channels;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    unsigned char *image = stbi_load(imagePath.c_str(),
                                     &width,
                                     &height,
                                     &channels,
                                     STBI_grey);

    char min = 0;
    char max = 255;
    for(int i = 0; i < width*height; ++i)
    {
        min = (image[i] < min) ? image[i]:min;
        max = (image[i] > max) ? image[i]:max;
    }

    std::cout << "(min, max) := (" << min << ", " << max << ")" << std::endl;

    //create buffers
    cl_mem memImage = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,width*height*sizeof(char),image,&error);
    cl_mem memHistogram = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,256*sizeof(int),&histogram,&error);

    //Create program, kernel and setting kernel args
    size_t programSize = programSource.length();
    const char * source = programSource.c_str();
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context,1,&source,&programSize,&error);
    error = clBuildProgram(program,1,&deviceId,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr);
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program,"computeHistogram",&error);

    error = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandQueue,memImage,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(cl_mem),&image,0,nullptr,nullptr);

    error = clSetKernelArg(kernel,0,sizeof(cl_mem),&memImage);
    error = clSetKernelArg(kernel,1,sizeof(cl_mem),&memHistogram);

    clFinish(commandQueue);

    size_t globalWorkSize = width*height;
    error = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue,kernel,1,nullptr,&globalWorkSize,nullptr,0,nullptr,nullptr);

    error = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandQueue,memHistogram,CL_TRUE,0,256*sizeof(int),&histogram,0,nullptr,nullptr);

    clFinish(commandQueue);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueue);
    clReleaseContext(context);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cl_platform_id platformId;
    cl_device_id deviceId;
    cl_context context;
    cl_command_queue commandQueue;
    setup(platformId,deviceId,context,commandQueue);

    std::string filename = "gray.jpeg";
    std::string programSource =
            "__kernel void computeHistogram(\n"
            " __global char * image, __global int * histogram)\n"
            "{\n"
            "   size_t idx = get_global_id(0);\n"
            "   char pixelValue = image[idx];\n"
            "   atomic_inc(&histogram[pixelValue]);\n"
            "}\n";

    int histogram[256] = {0};

    run(filename,programSource, deviceId, context, commandQueue,histogram);

    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "i : " << histogram[i] << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

However I get `0` in every bin. I think the logic I'm trying to apply is correct, but I cannot figure what the error is.

Comment: You do not check error return codes from opencl functions. How do you want to know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems. To name a few:

1. `clCreateBuffer` returns error -38 (CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT) because host_ptr is being passed and this is not being reflected in the `flags` parameter. `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` can be used in addition to `CL_MEM_READ_ONLY` and `CL_MEM_READ_WRITE` respectively.
2. To `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` size of `cl_mem` object is being passed instead of the size of `image` buffer.
3. After `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` again `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` is being used. I suspect the intention here was to read data back and for that `clEnqueueReadBuffer` needs to be used.

There may be more problems. These are just the major ones and it's hard to imagine that you checked cl functions return codes and all of them returned `CL_SUCCESS`...

Comment: I made a couple of changes this morning before checking the errors. I removed the comment in my post since the code is slightly different.

Comment: Is the use of `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` necessary, I've seen few examples (one of which regarding vectors additions) that doesn't really use it.

Answer (score 0):

The actual program that works is the following:

```
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>
#include <algorithm>

//Getting platform, device, context and command queue
void setup(
        cl_platform_id &platformId, cl_device_id &deviceId, cl_context& context, cl_command_queue& commandQueue,
        std::string platformName = "NVIDIA CUDA",  cl_device_type deviceType = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,
        std::string deviceName = "GeForce GTX 1070")
{

    using std::vector;
    using std::string;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    cl_uint numberOfPlatforms, numberOfDevices;
    cl_int error;

    //Finding platform id
    error = clGetPlatformIDs(0,nullptr,&numberOfPlatforms);
    vector<cl_platform_id> platform(numberOfPlatforms);
    error = clGetPlatformIDs(numberOfPlatforms,platform.data(),nullptr);

    for(const auto & currentPlatform : platform)
    {
        size_t stringSize;
        error = clGetPlatformInfo(currentPlatform,CL_PLATFORM_NAME,0,nullptr,&stringSize);
        char * currentPlatformName = new char[stringSize];
        error = clGetPlatformInfo(currentPlatform,CL_PLATFORM_NAME,stringSize,currentPlatformName,nullptr);
        if(string(currentPlatformName).compare(platformName) == 0)
        {
            cout << "Platform " << platformName << " found!" << endl;
            delete [] currentPlatformName;
            platformId = currentPlatform;
            break;
        }
        delete [] currentPlatformName;
    }

    error = clGetDeviceIDs(platformId,deviceType,0,nullptr,&numberOfDevices);
    vector<cl_device_id> device(numberOfDevices);
    error = clGetDeviceIDs(platformId,deviceType,numberOfDevices,device.data(),nullptr);

    for(const auto & currentDevice : device)
    {
        size_t stringSize;
        error = clGetDeviceInfo(currentDevice,CL_DEVICE_NAME,0,nullptr,&stringSize);
        char * currentDeviceName = new char[stringSize];
        error = clGetDeviceInfo(currentDevice,CL_DEVICE_NAME,stringSize,currentDeviceName,nullptr);

        if(string(currentDeviceName).compare(deviceName) == 0)
        {
            cout << "Device " << deviceName << " found!" << endl;
            delete [] currentDeviceName;
            deviceId = currentDevice;
            break;
        }
        delete [] currentDeviceName;
    }

    context = clCreateContext(nullptr,1,&deviceId,nullptr,nullptr,&error);
    commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context,deviceId,0,&error);

}

void run(const std::string & imagePath, const std::string& programSource, const cl_device_id deviceId,
        const cl_context& context, const cl_command_queue& commandQueue, int histogram[256])
{
    cl_int error;
    int width, height, channels;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    unsigned char *image = stbi_load(imagePath.c_str(),
                                     &width,
                                     &height,
                                     &channels,
                                     STBI_grey);

    unsigned char min = 255;
    unsigned char max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < width*height; ++i)
    {
        min = (image[i] < min) ? image[i]:min;
        max = (image[i] > max) ? image[i]:max;
    }

    std::cout << "(min, max) := (" << static_cast<int>(min) << ", " << static_cast<int>(max) << ")" << std::endl;

    //create buffers
    cl_mem memImage = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,width*height*sizeof(unsigned char),image,&error);
    cl_mem memHistogram = clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,256*sizeof(int),&histogram,&error);

    //Create program, kernel and setting kernel args
    size_t programSize = programSource.length();
    const char * source = programSource.c_str();
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context,1,&source,&programSize,&error);
    error = clBuildProgram(program,1,&deviceId,nullptr,nullptr,nullptr);
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program,"computeHistogram",&error);

    error = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandQueue,memImage,CL_TRUE,0,width*height*sizeof(unsigned char),image,0,nullptr,nullptr);

    error = clSetKernelArg(kernel,0,sizeof(cl_mem),&memImage);
    error = clSetKernelArg(kernel,1,sizeof(cl_mem),&memHistogram);

    clFinish(commandQueue);

    const size_t globalWorkSize = width*height;
    error = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue,kernel,1,nullptr,&globalWorkSize,nullptr,0,nullptr,nullptr);

    error = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue,memHistogram,CL_TRUE,0,256*sizeof(int),histogram,0,nullptr,nullptr);

    clFinish(commandQueue);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueue);
    clReleaseContext(context);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cl_platform_id platformId;
    cl_device_id deviceId;
    cl_context context;
    cl_command_queue commandQueue;
    setup(platformId,deviceId,context,commandQueue);

    std::string filename = "gray.jpeg";
    std::string programSource =
            "__kernel void computeHistogram(\n"
            " __global unsigned char * image, __global int * histogram)\n"
            "{\n"
            "   size_t idx = get_global_id(0);\n"
            "   unsigned char pixelValue = image[idx];\n"
            "   atomic_inc(&histogram[pixelValue]);\n"
            "   barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);"
            "}\n";

    int histogram[256] = {0};

    run(filename,programSource, deviceId, context, commandQueue,histogram);

    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << " : " << histogram[i] << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The main issue the line

```
error = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue,memHistogram,CL_TRUE,0,256*sizeof(int),histogram,0,nullptr,nullptr);
```

In the original post this was a `clEnqueueWriteBuffer` and the size was wrong. I was also using `char` instead of `unsigned char` and finally the kernel is different.